# Datatable ajax URL app. context

Tags: jquery, html, spring-boot, datatable, datatables

I have this definition of a Datatable defined on a Thymeleaf template of a SpringBoot application, using Datatables:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/   

$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#workerEventTable').dataTable( {
        order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        select: true,
        bLengthChange: false,
        stateSave: true,
        pageLength: 20,
        ajax: '/acerinox/api/workerevent/datatableList', /*acerinox is the app context*/     
           "columns": [
               { data: 'id' },
               { data: 'deviceId' },
               { data: 'companyName' },
               { data: 'description' },
               { data: 'battery' },
               { data: 'dateTime' },
               { data: 'signal' },           
               { data: 'data' },
               { data: 'alarm' }
           ] 
    });
} );

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

I would like to know if there a way to get the app context from somewhere, but not hardcoded, even from a property file.

Comment: Can you define JavaScript vars and use those? Say `ajax: some.jsvar` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to get the app context, you can get your endpoint url by using thymeleaf :

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/   

var datatablesUrl = /*[[@{/api/workerevent/datatableList}]]*/ "";

$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#workerEventTable').dataTable( {
        order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        select: true,
        bLengthChange: false,
        stateSave: true,
        pageLength: 20,
        ajax: datatablesUrl ,      
           "columns": [
               { data: 'id' },
               { data: 'deviceId' },
               { data: 'companyName' },
               { data: 'description' },
               { data: 'battery' },
               { data: 'dateTime' },
               { data: 'signal' },           
               { data: 'data' },
               { data: 'alarm' }
           ] 
    });
} );

/*]]>*/
</script>
```